# gem installed but jekyll plugin unable to find it

Tags: rubygems, jekyll

I am installing less plugin for jekyll but placing this file to _plugins folder: https://gist.github.com/joshbrown/760265

I have run: **sudo gem install less**

I have verified the gem is installed using **gem list** : **less (2.6.0)**

Ran **gem env gemdir** : **/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0**

**gem which 'less'** : **/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/less-2.6.0/lib/less.rb**

although I am not able to find it using **bundle show --paths**

When I run it, it complains the gem has not been installed:

```
You are missing the library required for less. Please run:
 $ [sudo] gem install less
  Conversion error: Jekyll::LessConverter encountered an error while converting 'aa.less':
                    uninitialized constant Jekyll::LessConverter::FatalException Did you mean? SignalException
jekyll 3.5.1 | Error:  uninitialized constant Jekyll::LessConverter::FatalException
```

Mac version: El Capitan

Can someone tell me where I did wrong ?

Comment: I don't have this problem running on my mac using ruby 2.3.0, but when I try to build my jekyll site with the Docker jekyll image, using ruby 2.4.2, I get this problem, even if I'm doing `bundle exec jekyll serve`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using bundle you need to add it to the `Gemfile` as a gem dependency.

Then run `bundle install` and you will be able to see it with `bundle show` and run Jekyll with `bundle exec jekyll serve`.